# Unable to resolve No matching version found for gatsby-cli@next

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, installation, gatsby

I have tried running the following command with and without sudo, I'm unable to install gatsby.
`npm install --global gatsby@next gatsby-cli@next`
here are my errors.

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for gatsby-cli@next.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-08T11_08_10_903Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@next` in npm refers to a `tag`. In this case, there's no `tag` for `gatsby-cli`. By default, if you run:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

It will take the latest version of the `gatsby-cli` package.

You can check for further details in [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag).

Comment: It says success, but i got a lot deprecated warnings, is that okay? or should I resolve that before moving on further?

Comment: They are dev dependencies warnings of the `gatsby-cli` dependency itself. They doesn't concern you at all and you can't avoid them. You don't have to worry at all. Since it's a released version your package will be safe.